# How to remove an environment from Conda

Tags: python, conda

In Windows Server 2012 R2 I have 3 environments in `Conda` right now-

```
1. <base>
2. <py_27>
3. <py_3>
```

I need to remove `py_27`. How do I do it ?

Comment: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html

Comment: Try reading the docs mate...

Comment: Please clarify which aspect(s) of this particular situation are not covered by the many existing resources available.

Answer (score 1):

As official documentation [says](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#removing-an-environment):

`conda remove --name py_27 --all`